# How to calculate weight of two stocks without knowing their correlation?

Tags: equities, risk-free

I have difficulty to solve attached question. The question asks me to find new weight of stocks by just changing standard deviation of the portfolio. I really do not have any idea how to solve it. Maybe the key point is the risk-free asset but I am not sure, can somebody give me a hint?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to create a new portfolio using the tangency portfolio $P_t$ and the risk-free rate $r$.

You know that the volatility of the tangency portfolio $\sigma_{P_t}=0.20$.

You also know that the risk-free asset has:

- No risk: $\sigma_r=0$
- Is not correlated with anything $\rho_{P_t,r} = 0$

So you're asked to create a portfolio with a higher risk, which means you are going to need to borrow some money to buy more of the tangency portfolio (you *leverage*).

You know that, by definition of volatility, the volatility of a portfolio $P$ formed of the tangency portfolio with weight $w$ and the risk-free asset with weight $1-w$ is :

$$\sigma_P^2 = w^2 \sigma_{P_t}^2 + (1-w)^2 \sigma_r^2 + 2w(1-w)\sigma_{P_t}\sigma_r\rho_{P_t,r} = w^2 \sigma_{P_t}^2$$

You hence get

$$w = \frac{\sigma_P}{\sigma_{P_t}} = \frac{0.24}{0.20} = 1.2$$

So the overall weight of the tangency portfolio will be $w=1.2$, the weight of the risk-free asset will be $1-w = -0.2$ (short). Within tangency portfolio, nothing has change in terms of weighting so you just multiply the 1.2 by the original weights which yields $w_A = 0.60 \cdot 1.2 =0.72$ and $w_B = 0.40 \cdot 1.2 =0.48$.

Comment: I do not know how to thank you my friend. All the best wishes for you..